# Error while installing face-recognition in python

Tags: python

How to solve following error I am getting when I am trying to install `face-recognition`?

`Command ""C:\Users\Dayavaan's\PycharmProjects\facerecognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "c:\users\dayavaan's\pycharmprojects\facerecognition\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py" prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\tmp1jciwnu9" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-bctlm_f6\numpy`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoygp.png) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

> just try this steps:

1. 1)**Microsoft Visual Studio 2018** (or newer) with C/C++ Compiler
   installed.
2. Use **Python 3.6.5(64-bit)** or above
3. Install **CMake**
   for windows and add it to your system environment variables.
4. Just run on cmd with this commands **pip install dlib** and then **pip install face_recognition**.

> let me Know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed it properly. That's why this error persists.
Use this official installation guide to install this package properly.
https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/

This package required some dlibs. So follow the steps here:
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508